# Do Revives still give points for the kill to the other team?

Tags: blacklight-retribution

So I bought the Revival Injector equipment, and I start to play Team Deathmatch, and a teammate dies. If I revive them, does the enemy team still receive a point? Do they get another point if that teammate dies after being revived? What if they choose not to accept the revive, and simply respawn anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just reading up on my Blacklight: Retribution stuff and Found this:

If he goes down, odds are, whatever killed him is crippled enough that you may be able to clean up, pop a revival pack, and you two are off again. **Just make sure the area is clear, because it does count as a second kill if he goes down while he's getting up**. It may be to your advantage (if it was just the two of you) to wind up dying to make sure, because you'll at least spawn with him again. That's the difference between three points and two. Assume you're already dead.

Found under Part 4. Revival Pack

[Source](http://blacklight-forum.perfectworld.com/showthread.php?t=369011)

Comment: It's been my experience that you get the CP regardless of whether your teammate uses the injector. Though you may get more if they do; I can't recall.